# images not showing despite using add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');

Tags: post-thumbnails, images, add-theme-support

I've got a system for post images where I have a specific category's post thumbnail shown in the header, with a cropped version appearing in the blog `#preview`, and the full size image appearing in the full post.

Images are not appearing in any of the 3 locations, and I'm not quite sure why.

functions.php-

```
<?php
    register_sidebar();

    if (function_exists('add_theme_support')) {
      add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
      set_post_thumbnail_size(140,170);
    }

    if ( function_exists( 'add_image_size' ) ) { 
    add_image_size( 'custom-image', 440, 265, true ); //(hard cropped)
    }

    function ravs_get_custom_image( $featured_img ){
    global $post, $posts;
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'numberposts' => 1,
        'post_status' => null,
        'post_parent' => $post->ID,
        'exclude' => $featured_img
    );

  $attachments = get_posts( $args );
     if ( $attachments ) {
        foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {          
           $img =  wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, 'custom-image' );
           return $img;
          }
     }else{
         echo 'Please attach images to your post';
     }
    }
?>
```

index.php

```
<?php echo get_header('cait');;?>
<?php echo get_sidebar();;?>

<div id="blog">
    <div class="preview">
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <div class="post-image">
            <?php echo ravs_get_custom_image( get_post_thumbnail_id () ); ?>
        </div><!-- end post-image -->
        <div class="post">
            <h2><?php the_title() ;?></h2>
            <span class="post-preview">
                <?php the_excerpt('read more...'); ?>
                <?php endwhile; else: ?>

                    <p>Sorry, no posts to list</p>

                <?php endif; ?>
            </span><!-- end post-preivew -->
            <p class="post-meta"><span style="font-family: amatic;">>></span>&nbsp;Posted on <?php the_date('M-d-y'); ?>&nbsp;<span style="font-family: amatic;">>></span>&nbsp;<?php the_tags('tags: ', ', ', '<br />'); ?></p><!-- end post-meta -->
        </div><!-- end post -->
    </div><!-- end preview -->
</div><!-- end blog -->


<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: You call `ravs_get_custom_image()` with an image's post ID, and then you exclude it in the `get_posts()` call in `ravs_get_custom_image()`.  Why?  (Also, you can double-check your post thumbnail ID with something like `echo( 'DEBUG: Thumbnail ID=' . get_post_thumbnail_id() . '<br />' );`.)

Comment: @PatJ Truthfully, I've put all of this together through use of this forum and various tutorials. This is my first attempt at something this complex, and while I am trying to learn along the way it's possible I've missed something. 
Am I correct in understanding that I should remove `'exclude' => $featured_img` from functions.php? (Doing that makes no changes to the site.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you appear to be using Featured Images, replace this:

```
<div class="post-image">
    <?php echo ravs_get_custom_image( get_post_thumbnail_id () ); ?>
</div><!-- end post-image -->
```

with this:

```
<div class="post-image">
    <?php
        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
            the_post_thumbnail( 'custom-image' );
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

#### References

Codex:
[`has_post_thumbnail()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_post_thumbnail)
[`the_post_thumbnail()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail)

Comment: Excellent.  Experience has taught me that WordPress handles a lot of this stuff for you, out of the box; sometimes it's just a matter of scrolling through the [Codex's Function Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/).